# a Thank you for the swag and a Happy New Year's greetings to all

Tags: discussion, announcements, swag

I just got the GIS swag and wanted to thank all the Stackexchange staff and the GIS moderators. The swag arrived just in time to count as a New Year's gift ( the jewish new year holiday is in two days time), and I wanted to take the opportunity to wish all of us, no matter what religion, ethnicity or nationality we belong to, a HAPPY NEW YEAR, a year of health, joy, happiness and a lot of professional GIS interest and fun family-time.